# What would cause a redirect from example.com to www.example.com, not to work?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using a very standard set of Rewrite rules for redirecting to the www domain. It works on one of my servers but not on the other.

I cant for the life of me figure out the problem because the other rewrite rules work except this one.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Is there some apache config setting that I need to change, or some conflicting rewrite rule?

Comment: What do your server logs show when you enable verbose rewrite logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the [L] rule in your redirect bozo! Yeah that fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

Things that can make this goes wrong:

1. You put the rules in a .htaccess and .htaccess are disabled by a `AllowOverride None`
2. You put the rules in a`<Location>` tag, [that's unsupported](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (seach Location in that page)
3. You put the rule in a `DirectoryMatch` directive and **your directory is not matching the expression** (not related, this rule could be put outside any Directory tag, it would be faster)
4. You put this in an apache configuration file and **forgot to reload apache** (or you made a gracefull reload and it's stalled, try a hard reload)
5. You put a rewriteRule before that one that is applied and **this one is never read** (a [L] tag?)
6. you were drunk and edited the production server settings while you are testing the pre-production website, more seriously check that this instruction is in the VirtualHost which really **match Servername or ServerAlias** of example.com.
7. ### you do not have **mod_rewrite enabled** on this server and this is in a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section
8. If you are redirected to a wrong place maybe you previously made a mistake, but the **301-permanent** code imply your browser will not even re-call your fixed webserver until you close and re-open the browser

If you do not find do what @larsk said you to do, enable rewriteLog, especially to debug the #5.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts, it was actually missing the [L] last constant